# Hawking radiation: direct matter -> energy conversion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation

When a [black hole evaporates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Evaporation), does it turn all the matter that has fallen in directly to energy, or will it somehow throw back out the same kind of matter (normal or anti) that went in?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20905/if-an-anti-matter-singularity-and-a-normal-matter-singularity-of-equal-masses

Comment: Black holes have no hair: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem so they don't remember what fell in.

Comment: If you're hoping to jump into a black hole, examine it, and hawking-radiate yourself out, my advice is to abandon your research now ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black hole has no knowledge of what kind of matter went in. As long as it went in it disappeared in the black hole. 
To create particles, it needs to fulfill conservation laws, which is not easy and black hole produces generally photons. 
However, take into account that evaporation of a black hole is extremely slow. For a black hole of reasonable size this time far exceeds universe lifetime.