# Event Horizons and Events

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, time, collision, event-horizon

How can two black holes with event horizons merge within the lifetime of the universe? Basically events are happening where events stop (to the outside observer) so does an event horizon actually exist? According to gravitational wave detectors on Earth, two black holes merged within fractions of a second.

Comment: Here is a related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26478/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [So Black Holes Actually Merge! In 1/5th of a Second - How?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235307/)

Comment: Also [Can black holes actually merge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26478/)