# Can antimatter becomes black hole?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, black-holes, collision, antimatter

I know it seems unlikely to accumulate sufficient amount of antimatter to let it collapse under its own weight to become a black hole(maybe the gravity works differently I don't know) since they will definitely react aggressively with ordinary matter which made up most of our known universe producing energy.

My question is can we accelerate antimatters and then let them collide with enough energy to produce a tiny black hole? would this tiny black hole shares similar properties with its normal counterparts?

Oops I almost forgot what kind of particles are produced in the abovementioned collision? (e.g. antiproton-antiproton)

Comment: Regarding gravity and antimatter - the mass-energy is the same, but charge, spin etc are reversed. as long as mass-energy is positive you get the effect of attractive gravitation (due to the curvature it generates). on that note - negative mass-energy is highly speculative as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5615/).